# Symmetries of lattice model of Weyl semimetal

Tags: solid-state-physics, symmetry, fermions, crystals, weyl-semimetal

Lattice model of (Time Reversal symmetry breaking) Weyl semimetal is given by Hamiltonian:
$$t_x\big((\cos(k_x a)-\cos(k_0 a)) + t_y(\cos k_y b -1) + t_z(\cos {k_z c} -1) \big)\sigma_x + t_y(\sin(k_y b))\sigma_y+t_z(\sin(k_z c))\sigma_z.$$

How can you explore the crystal symmetries of Weyl semimetal?
I am working with lattice parameter $a = b \neq c$. Hence the crystal structure is tetragonal. How can I check the rotational and reflective symmetry of this tetragonal lattice?

Comment: It's not clear to me what exactly you are asking, anyway a=b≠c still holds for hexagonal structures. More generally and precisely, the lattice parameters are defined by the symmetry, but not vice-versa. For example, if the symmetry properties are the same along a and b, then lattice paramters a and b must be equal. If the symmetry properties are different along a and b, the lattice paramtera and b can be different, but in special cases could also be coincident.

Comment: I understand that my question is a bit confusing. Let me rephrase that slightly:   In http://arxiv.org/abs/1610.02013 among others, a minimal model of Weyl semimetals is discussed.  Since TaAs has broken inversion symmetry, if we put its lattice parameters in such hamiltonian, is it is model for TaAs? Other symmetries of TaAs are there in hamiltonian?